# Destroy() in Basic Controller is not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I'm printing user complaints in table where I'm also printing a Delete button with every row. When I click that delete button, I want to delete that specific complaint from the table. I'm not using Resource Controller for this but a Basic Controller. Now, this is my code:

**ViewComplaint.blade.php** (Complaints Table with Delete Button):

```
<table id="cTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Student Name</th>
         <th>Complaint Title</th>
         <th>Complaint Description</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach($complaints as $complaint)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $complaint->name }}</td>
         <td>{{ $complaint->cname }}</td>
         <td>{{ $complaint->cbody }}</td>
         <td class="btn-group">
            {!! Form::open(array('route'=>['complaint.destroy',$complaint->id],'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Delete',['type'=>'submit','style'=>'border-radius: 0px;','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-sm',$complaint->id]) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
         </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Web.php** (Routes):

```
Route::get('/complaint/create','ComplaintController@create')->name('complaint.create');
Route::post('/complaint','ComplaintController@store')->name('complaint.store');
Route::get('/complaint','ComplaintController@index')->name('complaint.index');
Route::delete('/complaint/{$complaint->id}','ComplaintController@destroy')->name('complaint.destroy');
```

**ComplaintController.php** (Basic Controller):

```
class ComplaintController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $complaints = Complaint::all();
        return view('viewcomplaint',compact('complaints'));
    }

    public function create(User $user) {
        $user = User::all();
        $user->name = Auth::user()->name;
        return view('createcomplaint',compact('user'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request, Complaint $complaint, User $user) {
        $user =  User::find($user);
        $complaint->name = Auth::user()->name;
        $complaint->cname = $request->input('cname');
        $complaint->cbody = $request->input('cbody');

        //update whichever fields you need to be updated
        $complaint->save();
        return redirect()->route('home.index');
    }

    public function destroy(Complaint $complaint,$id)
    {
        $complaint = Complaint::findOrFail($complaint->id);
        $complaint->delete();
        return redirect()->route('complaint.index');
    }
}
```

Now when I click the Delete button on the table, it just gives me "404 | Not Found" error. What am I doing wrong here? I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: can you try removing the $id argument from the destroy() function and retrying perhaps?

Comment: Tried, same error

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

remove the $id from the route

```
Route::delete('/complain/{id}','ComplaintController@destroy')->name('complaint.destroy');

public function destroy($id) {

}
```

Comment: When I use $id instead of $complaint->id, it says "Undefined variable".

Answer (score 0):

The route parameter is just a name; you are saying this particular route segment is dynamic and I want the parameter named `complaint`:

```
Route::delete('complaint/{complaint}', 'ComplaintController@destroy')->name('complaint.destroy');
```

Then you can adjust your `destroy` method to take the parameter `complaint` typehinted as `Complaint $complaint` to get the implicit binding:

```
public function destroy(Complaint $complaint)
{
    $complaint->delete();

    return redirect()->route('complaint.index');
}
```

Comment: What do I pass in the button? Because If I'm still passing the complaint->id, the URL becomes "/complaint/{complaint->id}" and it says "Not Found".

Comment: you don't pass anything in the button, the form is what defines the action url

Comment: Still gives the 404 Error when I click delete.. This is my form:

`{!! Form::open(array('route'=>['complaint.destroy',$complaint],'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete',['type'=>'submit','style'=>'border-radius: 0px;','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}`

and this is my Controller: 

`public function destroy(Complaint $complaint)
    {
        $complaint->delete();
        return redirect()->route('complaint.index');
    }`

Comment: and what happens after you reach this 404 page? are you clicking back in your browser?

Comment: I'm going back to the url /complaint, reloading and then clicking delete again.

Comment: what is the url now?

Comment: When I click delete, the url is "complaint/1" and when I go back, it's "complaint"

Comment: that is the correct url for the delete URL ... assuming you are trying to delete complaint with id=1

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm confused as to why it still says "404: Not Found"

Comment: try changing 'method'=>'POST' in the form in your answer above and retry

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're defining your route wrong. Change your route to:

```
Route::delete('/complaint/{id}','ComplaintController@destroy')->name('complaint.destroy');
```

You don't need an array() in your form opening, so hange your form opening to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['complaint.destroy',$complaint->id]]) !!}
```

And remove the `$complaint->id` from your submit button, you don't need it there.

All you have to do now inside your function is to find `Complaint` that has the `id` you passed in your form:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $complaint = Complaint::findOrFail($id);
        $complaint->delete();
        return redirect()->route('complaint.index');
    }
```

Let me know if you stumble on any errors.

Comment: `array(1, 2, 3)` is the same as `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Yes it is, it's just easier to read, so there's no need to specify the array() method

Comment: makes it easier to forget to put the closing `]` on your array in your example ;)